# Kalman Filter for GPS android

Tags: android, gps, kalman-filter

To get a more accurate data from GPS, Kalman filter is being recommended. But I can't find any tutorial how to implement Kalman Filter for GPS, android.

Comment: Tnx for question, but consider this question for geodetic class of receiver is recommended.

Comment: Question is quite old and closed. But looking for the same task and I have found these two interesting projects. Maybe interesting for someone arriving here as me: 
https://github.com/villoren/KalmanLocationManager 
and
https://github.com/maddevsio/mad-location-manager
The second one uses also accelerometer and sensor data to improve tracks. I found it really interesting, although as the first answer says GPS Data is already heavily Kalman filtered.

Answer (score 11):

GPS Data are already heavily Kalman filtered. This is done inside the GPS receiver.
Dont expect an accuracy gain in position (lat / lon) if you create your own kalman filter.
Further you dont have the information that the internal GPS receiver had. It feeds its internal kalman filter 1000 time  / per second, before it outputs one location.

In your own post processing filter you might gain a smoother track (related to visualizing the positions). But smoother is not more accurate, only more pleasant to view.

Another topic is whether or not the GPS positions must be available in real time, e.g display the current position on screen. If you want to smooth your tracks afterwards (non realtime) you could be successfull, but I would not use a kalman filter for that case.
A kalman filter is well suited for real time filtering, for post processing, you could try a sliding average with a triangle window filter (easy to implement, while kalman is very komplex)

Comment: What about using a kalman filter on all of the signals coming from the Android? e.g. Location from Cell Tower, Location from GPS and Location from Wifi Hotspots.. Is the kalman filter beneficial in that instance?

Comment: No, if you have gps, then you don't need cell tower or WLAN locations. These are 3 different locationing techniques with much different accuracies. GPS is much more accurate than any of the others, so if you have GPS you can ignore the others. WLAN and cell twoer locations can be used e.g to load map data while GPS is not yet available. But there is no benfefit in kalman filtering all 3 together.

Comment: The source of location updates vary over time, sometimes they are GPS, sometimes they aren't. My project struggles when after a period of GPS updates the next update is a vague inaccurate cell tower location update. I was hoping I could use the Kalman Filter to minimise the effect that inaccurate update has on subsequent location updates.

Comment: No forget that. If you dont have GPS locations then you dont have a valid location. Most probably you will get better results when using GPS only. The cell tower locations are of limited use. (1km accuracy)

Answer (score 6):

There’s a lot of stuff you can find through Google and Wikipedia, but having a basic intuition could be useful.

Essentially, a Kalman filter means repeatedly applying a two-step process:

1. Make a guess
2. Use a measurement to update the guess

A Kalman filter formalizes a simple idea: when you know how fast you’re going, you can predict your geolocation from the last reported GPS position, and then update when a new GPS report comes in.

We will talk about two variables here: the **mean**, which is your best guess, and your **uncertainty**, which represents the accuracy of that guess. In terms of GPS, you would be talking about the GPS location and the margin of error (e.g. 10 meters).

With every update you do, you increase your uncertainty a bit because you’re not really that sure the velocity hasn’t changed. When a new measurement comes in, you update the position and the certainty.

The mean and uncertainty can be represented as a Bell curve (a normal distribution), with the variable on the X axis and the probability of it having that value on the Y axis:

[image: Normal distribution]

Here **µ** (mu) is the mean and **σ** (sigma) is the uncertainty. Any such curve can be described by these two values.

The trick is that you can actually multiple two bell curves (your prediction and your measurement) and get a new one representing the combined knowledge, which you’d do when you get a new GPS position after having done some predictions. You’ll find the math for this on Wikipedia and other sites.

Comment: Kalman is for linear motion as I understood. But Can't say GPS data as such. In my case, can I convert gps data to XY coordinates and then kalman filter and then again convert them?

Comment: @Marlio yes of course you can transform a coordinate given in (latitude, longitude) into cartesian plane. Every Map application does this while showing the position on your flat screen. This task is called "projection".